Buidling a Golang app in Docker returns 'cannot find module providing package' on 'go get .'
I'm working to containerize a Golang app using Docker, and I'm running into an issue with getting the executable to build from my Dockerfile.
Here is the Dockerfile:
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

FROM golang:1.22.2

WORKDIR /app

# Download Go modules
COPY go.mod go.sum ./
RUN go mod download

COPY *.go ./

RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -o /sac

EXPOSE 8080

# Run
CMD ["/sac"]

Pretty much ripped straight from the Docker documentation on building Go images. When I go to build this (docker build --tag sac-server .), I run into a bunch off errors that all look like this:
main.go:10:2: no required module provides package github.com/GenerateNU/sac/backend/config; to add it:
go get github.com/GenerateNU/sac/backend/config

I get a bunch of these for various modules in our package. The full project's name (defined in the (go.mod) is module github.com/GenerateNU/sac/backend, and in this example /config is a sub-package. Our directory looks like this:
backend
--->auth
--->config
--->constants
--->database
---><a bunch of other modules>
--->go.mod
--->go.sum
--->main.go
--->Dockerfile

And all the errors we're getting about 'no required modules' are submodules/packages referenced the main.go.
How do I go about fixing this? I've tried replacing the go mod download with go get -d -v . and go mod tidy, but I get the same errors. Thank you! In case I didn't provide enough info about our codebase, you can check out our repo link here: https://github.com/generateNU/sac

Looks like I've fixed my own problem. I found another answer on here with a similar problem and replaced my Dockerfile with this:
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

FROM golang:1.22.2

RUN mkdir /app
ADD . /app
WORKDIR /app

COPY go.mod go.sum ./

# Download all the dependencies
RUN go mod download

COPY . .


RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -a -installsuffix cgo -o main .

This builds successfully. We also had a .dockerignore that was ignoring two subpackages that are actually used in the main.go, so I removed that to get rid of those errors.

It works but downside is it creates a super-huge image.

Try use this one docker code
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM golang:1.22-alpine as builder

ENV GO111MODULE=on \
    CGO_ENABLED=0 \
    GOOS=linux \
    GOARCH=amd64

WORKDIR /build

RUN apk update && apk upgrade && \
    apk --no-cache add ca-certificates && \
    apk --no-cache add tzdata

COPY go.mod .
COPY go.sum .
COPY .env .
RUN go mod download

COPY . .

RUN go build -o test main.go

WORKDIR /dist

RUN cp /build/test .

# Build a small image
FROM gcr.io/distroless/static

# copy files
COPY --from=builder /dist/test /
COPY .env .

ENTRYPOINT [ "/test" ]

EXPOSE 27017

